# AttributeError running Django site on Mac 11.0.1

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, kombu

I'm getting an error running a django site locally that was working fine before I updated my Mac OS to 11.0.1. I'm thinking this update is the cause of the problem since nothing else was really changed between when it was working and now.

```
10:15:05 worker.1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
10:15:05 worker.1 |   File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 5, in <module>
10:15:05 worker.1 |     from celery.__main__ import main
10:15:05 worker.1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
10:15:05 worker.1 |     from celery import five  # noqa
10:15:05 worker.1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/five.py", line 20, in <module>
10:15:05 worker.1 |     from kombu.five import monotonic
10:15:05 worker.1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/five.py", line 56, in <module>
10:15:05 worker.1 |     absolute_to_nanoseconds = CoreServices.AbsoluteToNanoseconds
10:15:05 worker.1 |   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 379, in __getattr__
10:15:05 worker.1 |     func = self.__getitem__(name)
10:15:05 worker.1 |   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 384, in __getitem__
10:15:05 worker.1 |     func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
10:15:05 worker.1 | AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, AbsoluteToNanoseconds): symbol not found
```

Here is my brew config

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.6.0
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 1d5e354cc2ff048bd7161d95b3fa7f91dc9dd081
Last commit: 2 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: fdb83fcfb482e5ed1f1c3c442a85b99223fcabeb
Core tap last commit: 27 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_DISPLAY: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.rZ1F30XomO/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit icelake
Clang: 12.0 build 1200
Git: 2.24.3 => /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 14.0.2, 1.8.0_265
macOS: 11.0.1-x86_64
CLT: 12.3.0.0.1.1605054730
Xcode: 12.3 => /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11
```

Typically I'll run the site with a virtualenv running python 2.7.15, I was getting the same error with that. I reinstalled python with pyenv and remade the virtualenv but the same error appeared. I'm running Django 1.10.8 with Kombu 3.0.37

Comment: Does this help?: http://breedlovebreedlove.blogspot.com/2015/04/python-runtime-error-with-kombu-on-mac.html "... conflict in dyld_fallback_library_path environment variable between libraries used homebrew python ..."

Comment: `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't set anywhere so I don't think this is the solution

Comment: I'm having the same problem on my macbook arm with big sur... try to run this on debug mode with PyCharm, for it's working... but I don't know why...

Comment: Tried running in debug mode in PyCharm, same issue

Comment: oh I forgot to say that I was also using pyenv-virtualenv

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok this is a dirty workaround for Big Sur compatibility:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-big-sur-11_0_1-release-notes

> New in macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, the system ships with a built-in dynamic
> linker cache of all system-provided libraries. As part of this change,
> copies of dynamic libraries are no longer present on the filesystem.
> Code that attempts to check for dynamic library presence by looking
> for a file at a path or enumerating a directory will fail. Instead,
> check for library presence by attempting to dlopen() the path, which
> will correctly check for the library in the cache. (62986286)

so in order to find these libraries I just put the static paths in the find_library function at `<path to your Python 2 installation>/lib/python2.7/ctypes/util.py` just below `os.name == "posix" and sys.platform == "darwin"`:

```
if name == 'CoreServices':
    return '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices'
elif name == 'libSystem.dylib':
    return '/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib'
```

at the end it would look like this:

```
if os.name == "posix" and sys.platform == "darwin":
    from ctypes.macholib.dyld import dyld_find as _dyld_find
    def find_library(name):
        if name == 'CoreServices':
            return '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices'
        elif name == 'libSystem.dylib':
            return '/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib'

        possible = ['@executable_path/../lib/lib%s.dylib' % name,
                    'lib%s.dylib' % name,
                    '%s.dylib' % name,
                    '%s.framework/%s' % (name, name)]
        for name in possible:
            try:
                return _dyld_find(name)
            except ValueError:
                continue
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, works perfectly. Was really pulling my hair out over this one.

Comment: Little clarification: the change above (the extra if/elseif) should be added to the file `<path to your Python 2 installation>/lib/python2.7/ctypes/util.py`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the answer I upgraded to 11.4 anacoda refused to work. Now everytthing is okay. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me - thanks for this.  For what it's worth, I'm on macOS Monterey 12.3

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue after Bigsur 11.5.1 update (maybe, just coincidently). The answer provided above still works, but I was confused on what to do as I'm new to this. Here are the steps to follow:

1. Look at the error you get to find the path to the file `util.py` where your python 2.7 is installed. Open it using a text editor.
2. With the file opened, search for "posix", make sure it look like this `"posix" and sys.platform == "darwin"`.
3. Find the line `def find_library(name):`, and add the script in the answer above under it.

I have included screenshots for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A less invasive way of doing this would be to monkey patch `ctypes` dynamically, before invoking whatever code has the problem.  That way you can avoid editing core python files.

I ran into a very similar issue where an old version of celery would not start on MacOS, because of this same error from `import vine.five`.

Since celery is directly invoked as a script, the following patch to `bin/celery` in my virtualenv resolved the issue:

```
import os, sys
if os.name == "posix" and sys.platform == "darwin":
    import ctypes.util
    _old_ctypes_find_library = ctypes.util.find_library
    def _new_ctypes_find_library(name):
        if name == 'CoreServices':
            return '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices'
        elif name == 'libSystem.dylib':
            return '/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib'
        else:
            return _old_ctypes_find_library(name)
    ctypes.util.find_library = _new_ctypes_find_library
```